# How to expose and register one boost log core to another

Tags: c++, logging, boost, boost-log, boost-logging

A dll and an executable both use boost::log. They end up using different singleton log cores. How can I expose the dll core to the executable and register the dll-core to the exe-core so that I can redirect both into one logfile.

I wrote a minimal example to illustrate where I stumble:

LogUser.hpp

```
#pragma once

#ifdef DYNLIB_EXPORTS
#define DYNLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DYNLIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class DYNLIB_API LogUser
{
public:
    LogUser();
    ~LogUser() {}
};
```

LogUser.cpp

```
#include "LogUser.hpp"
#include <boost\log\trivial.hpp>
LogUser::LogUser()
{
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "LogUser constructed";
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>

#pragma comment (lib, "dynlib.lib")
#include <dynlib/LogUser.hpp>

void setupLogging();

int main()
{
    setupLogging();
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "main enter";
    LogUser dynamicLogUser;
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "main exit";
    return 0;
}

void setupLogging()
{
    using namespace boost::log;
    add_common_attributes();
    register_simple_formatter_factory< trivial::severity_level, char >("Severity");
    add_file_log
        (
        keywords::file_name = "file.log",
        keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%] [%ThreadID%] [%Severity%]: %Message%"
        );
}
```

LogUser compiles into LogUser.dll. The constructor of LogUser creates a trace message that ends up on the console. Main redirects its output to a log file but does not redirect the dll output to the same logfile. I suppose the dll contains its own logcore and I would have to redirect its messages to the other core first. I googled the problem and I can not find a simple solution although it feels like this should be a one line call in main during setup. And a getter to the boost logcore singleton in the dll interface.

Is there a standard way that I am missing? How would I redirect that logging here?

Edit #1: - output on my system and fiction of what I want to happen.
[image]

Edit #2: 
- I foubd a possible solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302123/how-can-i-use-boost-log-across-dll-boundaries).
- If that tip solves the problem I will delete this question due to being a clone.

Edit #3: 
I implemented the suggested solution from EDIT #2. It works but isn't what I want.

Essentially you are supposed to `#define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK` . Unfortunately that does not work since log is using other libraries that recursively also have to be added. I ended up with `#define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` .
All of boost is now made dynamic and with V1.59 that may be 30 dlls. In my minimal example I had to supply the dlls for chrono, date_time, filesystem, log_setup, log, regex, system and thread (.count = 8).

So even though the result is exactly that I wanted the way to get to it is different, this distinguishes this question from the other question.
The DLL approach ensures that there is only the one dll singleton of the core.
I prefer having 2 cores over having to supply the dlls so chaining the two together is acceptable for me.

Is there a way to get the same result while still linking statically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost.Log [requires](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/installation/config.html) to be built as a shared library if you use it from multiple modules. The library design is relying on that requirement, and the logging core is not the only singleton in the library. Depending on the library features you use, you are more or less likely to run into hard to debug problems if you violate this precondition. It is also possible that the code that works with your currently used version of Boost.Log will break with a different version.

Comment: You are involved in developing Boost.Log, is that correct? How do I get in touch with you? I would like to share a Vision about how this can be done and see if you think it is worth the effort. I would love to help realize the changes by contributing as a programmer.

Comment: Sure. You can submit pull requests and issues at GitHub: https://github.com/boostorg/log/. Discussions about the library are held on the Boost developers mailing list: http://www.boost.org/community/groups.html#main.

Answer (score 2):

This all boils down to global variables.  "Singleton" is just another name for a global variable.

If you link both your executable and your DLL statically against Boost, then they each have their own singleton (global variable).  If you want to share them, then you have to link both your executable and your DLL against a shared logging library so that they are sharing the same global singleton.

This is just the consequence of using shared libraries: they have a tendency to force other libraries to also be shared because of global data.

Comment: @legalze Thanks for the feedback - i was able to do what you describe but i still wonder if there is another (built in) way. One example could be to create a sink/logger. With one end connecting to one of the cores and the other end connecting to the other core. Since I do not know the design it may even be possible that the cores are a shell with an inner representation that can be joined. Both possibilities would allow for static linking and common logging. I am asking if something along those lines is possible with the boost log design.

Comment: The documentation just shows a single static getter for obtaining the core; there doesn't seem to be any way to share it other than through this global singleton.  So you're not left with any other options without modifying the source.